# When using docx4j in android to read word doc facing the following issue

Tags: android, docx4j

**Aim: To read content of a word doc onto the cosole**

Environment used: Windows 7 32bit
                  Eclipse IDE Indigo
                  Android 4.1 API 16
                  Java 1.6
Library :         docx4j-2.8.0

Following is the code snippet i am using to print text of word doc on console

```
WordprocessingMLPackage wordMLPackage = WordprocessingMLPackage.load(new java.io.File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath(), selectedFromList));

MainDocumentPart documentPart = wordMLPackage.getMainDocumentPart(); 
System.out.println("file contents --->>>>>" +documentPart.getContent());    

DocPropsCorePart docPropsCorePart = wordMLPackage.getDocPropsCorePart();
CoreProperties coreProps = (CoreProperties)docPropsCorePart.getJaxbElement();

System.out.println("'dc:title' is " + coreProps.getTitle().getValue().getContent().get(0));
System.out.println(coreProps.getTitle().getValue().getClass().getName() );
System.out.println("'dcterms:created' is " + coreProps.getCreated().getClass().getName() );
```

when i try to execute the above code i get the following issues
eclipse logcat displays the following logs

```
08-10 12:22:37.853: I/dalvikvm(1761): Could not find method javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.createMarshaller, referenced from method 

org.docx4j.openpackaging.packages.WordprocessingMLPackage.save
08-10 12:22:37.853: W/dalvikvm(1761): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 7579: Ljavax/xml/bind/JAXBContext;.createMarshaller ()Ljavax/xml/bind/Marshaller;
08-10 12:22:37.853: D/dalvikvm(1761): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0017

08-10 12:22:37.863: I/dalvikvm(1761): Could not find method javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.createMarshaller, referenced from method 

org.docx4j.openpackaging.packages.WordprocessingMLPackage.transform

08-10 12:22:37.863: W/dalvikvm(1761): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 7579: Ljavax/xml/bind/JAXBContext;.createMarshaller ()Ljavax/xml/bind/Marshaller;
08-10 12:22:37.863: D/dalvikvm(1761): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x000d

08-10 12:22:37.863: I/dalvikvm(1761): Failed resolving Lorg/docx4j/jaxb/JaxbValidationEventHandler; interface 1254 'Ljavax/xml/bind/ValidationEventHandler;'
08-10 12:22:37.863: W/dalvikvm(1761): Link of class 'Lorg/docx4j/jaxb/JaxbValidationEventHandler;' failed

08-10 12:22:37.873: D/dalvikvm(1761): DexOpt: unable to opt direct call 0x46db at 0x1e in Lorg/docx4j/openpackaging/packages/WordprocessingMLPackage;.transform
08-10 12:22:37.873: D/dalvikvm(1761): DexOpt: unable to opt direct call 0x1dba at 0x26 in Lorg/docx4j/openpackaging/packages/WordprocessingMLPackage;.transform

08-10 12:22:37.883: E/dalvikvm(1761): Could not find class 'org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.POIFSFileSystem', referenced from method 

org.docx4j.openpackaging.packages.OpcPackage.load

08-10 12:22:37.883: W/dalvikvm(1761): VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 1658 (Lorg/apache/poi/poifs/filesystem/POIFSFileSystem;) in 

Lorg/docx4j/openpackaging/packages/OpcPackage;
08-10 12:22:37.883: D/dalvikvm(1761): VFY: replacing opcode 0x22 at 0x001a

08-10 12:22:37.893: I/dalvikvm(1761): Could not find method javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.createUnmarshaller, referenced from method 

org.docx4j.openpackaging.packages.OpcPackage.load

08-10 12:22:37.893: W/dalvikvm(1761): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 7580: Ljavax/xml/bind/JAXBContext;.createUnmarshaller ()Ljavax/xml/bind/Unmarshaller;
08-10 12:22:37.893: D/dalvikvm(1761): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x004d

08-10 12:22:37.893: I/dalvikvm(1761): Could not find method javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.createMarshaller, referenced from method 

org.docx4j.openpackaging.packages.OpcPackage.save

08-10 12:22:37.893: W/dalvikvm(1761): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 7579: Ljavax/xml/bind/JAXBContext;.createMarshaller ()Ljavax/xml/bind/Marshaller;
08-10 12:22:37.893: D/dalvikvm(1761): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0017

08-10 12:22:37.905: D/dalvikvm(1761): DexOpt: unable to opt direct call 0x2654 at 0x1c in Lorg/docx4j/openpackaging/packages/OpcPackage;.load
08-10 12:22:37.905: D/dalvikvm(1761): DexOpt: unable to opt direct call 0x2651 at 0x21 in Lorg/docx4j/openpackaging/packages/OpcPackage;.load

08-10 12:22:37.905: I/dalvikvm(1761): Failed resolving Lorg/docx4j/jaxb/JaxbValidationEventHandler; interface 1254 'Ljavax/xml/bind/ValidationEventHandler;'
08-10 12:22:37.905: W/dalvikvm(1761): Link of class 'Lorg/docx4j/jaxb/JaxbValidationEventHandler;' failed

08-10 12:22:37.905: D/dalvikvm(1761): DexOpt: unable to opt direct call 0x46db at 0x53 in Lorg/docx4j/openpackaging/packages/OpcPackage;.load
08-10 12:22:37.963: W/System.err(1761): org.docx4j.openpackaging.exceptions.Docx4JException: Error reading from the stream

08-10 12:22:37.963: W/System.err(1761):     at org.docx4j.openpackaging.packages.OpcPackage.load(OpcPackage.java:239)
08-10 12:22:37.963: W/System.err(1761):     at org.docx4j.openpackaging.packages.OpcPackage.load(OpcPackage.java:195)
08-10 12:22:37.963: W/System.err(1761):     at org.docx4j.openpackaging.packages.OpcPackage.load(OpcPackage.java:178)
08-10 12:22:37.963: W/System.err(1761):     at org.docx4j.openpackaging.packages.WordprocessingMLPackage.load(WordprocessingMLPackage.java:172)
08-10 12:22:37.975: W/System.err(1761):     at com.reader.MainActivity$2.onItemClick(MainActivity.java:125)
08-10 12:22:37.975: W/System.err(1761):     at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:298)
08-10 12:22:37.975: W/System.err(1761):     at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1086)
08-10 12:22:37.975: W/System.err(1761):     at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:2855)
08-10 12:22:37.975: W/System.err(1761):     at android.widget.AbsListView$1.run(AbsListView.java:3529)
08-10 12:22:37.984: W/System.err(1761):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
08-10 12:22:37.984: W/System.err(1761):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
08-10 12:22:37.984: W/System.err(1761):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-10 12:22:37.984: W/System.err(1761):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
08-10 12:22:37.984: W/System.err(1761):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-10 12:22:37.993: W/System.err(1761):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-10 12:22:37.993: W/System.err(1761):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
08-10 12:22:37.993: W/System.err(1761):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
08-10 12:22:37.993: W/System.err(1761):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-10 12:22:38.085: W/System.err(1761): Caused by: java.io.IOException: Mark has been invalidated.
08-10 12:22:38.085: W/System.err(1761):     at java.io.BufferedInputStream.reset(BufferedInputStream.java:350)
08-10 12:22:38.093: W/System.err(1761):     at org.docx4j.openpackaging.packages.OpcPackage.load(OpcPackage.java:237)

08-10 12:22:38.923: I/Choreographer(1761): Skipped 107 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
```

Answer (score 2):

**Disclosure: I work on the docx4j project**

You need to be using the [Android-specific branch of docx4j](https://github.com/plutext/docx4j/tree/android).

See [jaxb-can-be-made-to-run-on-android](http://www.docx4java.org/blog/2012/05/jaxb-can-be-made-to-run-on-android/)

I'd suggest you get [AndroidDocxToHtml](https://github.com/plutext/AndroidDocxToHtml) working first, and then move on from there.

Comment: Hi, I am trying to use docx4j on android, and I've seen that post, I'm still confused on how to get it working. when i compile the example from github I get: `com.android.dx.util.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lcom/topologi/diffx/Constants;` could you please help me?

Comment: Sounds like you have 2 copies of the docx4j jar there.

Comment: I only see 1 docx4j jar file in the libs folder.

Answer (score 0):

Answer refers to the IOException "Mark has been invalidated":
I'm using the Android branch of docx4j and encounter the same errorwhen trying to load a template DOCX. I changed to load the docx-file the following way which solved my problem:

```
        final LoadFromZipNG loader = new LoadFromZipNG();
        mypackage= (WordprocessingMLPackage)loader.get(is);
```

Taken from the DOCX4J-Sample: https://github.com/plutext/AndroidDocxToHtml